# OpenCV library file not present(imgproc.hpp) in Windows

Tags: opencv, build

I am a newbie to OpenCV. Followed the openCV tutorial. Now when i Build the project, the error comes. It says the include directory imgproc.hpp was not found. When i checked in the opencv/include/opencv2 folder, there were no imgproc.hpp and ml.hpp and video.hpp files. Please help. Working on Win32 and OpenCV2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be missing a directory, try: `opencv/include/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp`

Comment: Yes its a file. But its not present in the Opencv/include/opencv2 folder. Where it is supposed to be. Also other files i named here are not present in that folder.

Comment: yes, in opencv/include/opencv2 only 1 file is present, that's named opencv and nothing else. No other directory in it. Is there a problem with my installation .

Comment: Search in the OpenCV installation directory where is `imgproc.hpp`. I'm sure Windows provide a SEARCH functionality. I suspect there is more than 1 `include` folders.

Comment: Yes, i found two imgproc.hpp files. One at opencv/build/include/opencv/opencv2/imgproc and other at opencv/modules/imgproc/include/opencv2/improc. i can use any one of them, right?

Comment: I suggest you use the first: `opencv/build/include/opencv/opencv2/imgproc`. Don't forget to up vote my answer if it helped you, or select it as the official answer by clicking in the checkbox near it. Doing this keeps the forum organized and helps future visitors to solve their problem as well.